# Tapestry 5.4 Beanedit form alert

Tags: java, tapestry

How can I hide this alert in my beanedit form. It's really annoying.

[image]

I tried with this css code but it didn't work.

```
.alert-dismissable .alert .alert-danger{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. 
In my css file I added

```
.bean > .alert{
    display: none !important;
}
```

After that I just added the class `bean` to the form.
Thats it no more alerts.